# Let $X$ be $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$. Let $A \subset X $ be the set of all characteristic maps. Show that the constant map $g$ belongs to the closure of $A$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be the product space $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$. Let $A \subset X $ be the set of all characteristic functions of finite sets. Show that the constant map $g, g(x) = 1$ belongs to the closure of $A$.

In order to show that some $x \in \overline{A}$ I need to show that for every open nbdh $U_x$ the property $A \cap U_x \ne \emptyset$ holds.

Now I don’t know exactly how to approach the problem is it so that I would need to show that for every nbdh of the constant map $g$ I need to satisfy the property I stated preivously?

Comment: Do you know what the open sets of $\mathbb R^\mathbb R$ are?

Comment: To be honest I don’t know exactly what $\Bbb{R}^{\Bbb{R}}$ is supposed to mean...

Comment: Well that's a problem, isn't it. Lucky for you, the answer is all over the internet.

Comment: It seems that it’s defined as the set $\{f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R \}$. So the set of all functions from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.

Comment: Indeed. So what's the topology on the space?

Comment: Let me see if I got this right. You have posted a topological question about $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ without knowing which topology you are supposed to be working with. Am I right?

Comment: I have posted a topological question that’s supposed to deal with product spaces, but I’m not entirely sure how $\Bbb{R}^{\Bbb{R}}$ is a product space.

Comment: The projections on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ are just the evaluations $p_x(f)= f(x)$ for each $x \in \Bbb R$, the product topology is the smallest opology that makes all $p_x$ continuous.

Answer (score 1):

If $U$ is a basic open neighbourhood of $g$, it is of the form $U = \bigcap_{x \in F} p_x^{-1}[U_x]$ for a finite subset $F \subseteq \Bbb R$ and for each $x$, $p_x:\Bbb R^{\Bbb R} \to \Bbb R$ is the projection $p_x(f)=f(x)$ and each $U_x, x \in F$ is a real neighbourhood of $1$.
This is by the definition of the product topology on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$.

This $U$ thus contains $\chi_F$ by definition: $p_x(\chi_F)=\chi_F(x) =1 \in U_x$ for all $x \in F$, so $\chi_F \in \bigcap_{x \in F} p_x^{-1}[U_x] = U$.

As every *basic* neighbourhood of $g$ intersects $A$, it follows trivially that $g \in \overline{A}$ too.

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by ”basic” here?

Comment: @Wondera coming from the standard base for the product topology.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the question is in the context of the product topology on the Cartesian product $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} = \prod_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}$  based on the usual metric topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Then convergence in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is just pointwise convergence (i.e. convergence of each projection), so done.